# Laravel Eloquent Join 2 Tables

Tags: php, join, laravel-4, eloquent

These are my models:

```
class Branch extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'tb_branch';

    public function faculty() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Faculty');
    }
}

class Faculty extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'tb_faculty';

    public function branch() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Branch');
    }

}
```

In branch table I have set a column with foreign key `user_id` that links to users table.

In faculty table I have set a column with foreign key `branch` which links to branch table with column `name`.

And now I need to retrieve Faculty data based on currently logged in user (with Eloquent).

I imagine the work flow would be:

- retrieve id of currently logged in user
- link that id to the branch's `user_id` and retrieve branch's `name`
- link that branch's `name` to faculty branch's `name` and retrieve all matched faculty data

Now this is what I have tried, it didn't work:

```
$user_id = Sentry::getUser();
$faculty = Faculty::with('branch')->where('branch.user_id',$user->id)->get();
```

Error says:

> Unknown column 'branch.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
>   `tb_faculty` where `branch`.`user_id` = 6)

How can I achieve this with Eloquent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
retrieve id of currently logged in user
link that id to the branch's user_id and retrieve branch's name
link that branch's name to faculty branch's name and retrieve all matched faculty data
```

so, first way:

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$branch = Branch::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->first();
$faculties = Faculty::where('branch_name', '=', $branch->name)->get();
```

second way:

if faculties are based on name, then:

```
class Branch extends Eloquent {

   public function faculties() {

    return Faculty::where('branch_name', '=', $this->name)->get();
    /*

     or do this: return $this->hasMany('Faculty', 'branch_name', 'name');       

    */

   }


}
```

Then do this:

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$faculties = Branch::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->first()->faculties;
```

then in the view:

```
foreach($faculties as $fac)
{

  echo $fac->name.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my first solution, but i was trying to using join so the query is only one line and minimize database connection

Comment: Your second solution on faculties function works `return $this->hasMany('Faculty', 'branch_name', 'name');`. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: yes strings fields can also be joined :), glad to help